# In React.js : Is it possible to only access parts of a children component?

Tags: reactjs

Here's the story: I have been in intern in a company for 3 and a half week now (for the end of my first year of programming studies), and my mission is to integrate automated translation in their React web app so that it only translates some of the text (we don't want names or product names to be translated, obviously).

The problem I have isn't the translation part, I already developed a functional REST API ready to be used. The issue I have is that I can't find a way to ONLY access marked parts of a children component from its parent. I managed to do it simply with a document.getElementsByClassName in vanilla js and simple HTML, but not in React.

Here's a quick example of the principle I want to apply:

This is the component that would contain the original text of the app (you will notice I plan on calling the translator component as a wrapper to acces the content of its children).

```
import React from "react";
import {Translator} from "./Translator.js";

export class Content1 extends React.Component {
  content = (
    <div>
      <p> Hey! Regarde cet article, il a l'air top! </p>
      <p className="translate">
        Hippolyte Romain, né le 28 août 1947 à Paris, est un illustrateur,
        peintre et écrivain français. Il travaille d'abord dans les milieux de
        la mode et de la couture, se spécialisé dans la connaissance du xviiie
        siècle, et sa vie et son travail se partagent entre la France et la
        Chine. Il est le directeur artistique du jardin d'acclimatation de
        Paris.
      </p>
      <p className="translate"> Tu me diras ce que tu en penses! </p>
    </div>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <Translator>
         {this.content}
      </Translator>
    );
  }
}
```

Inside the Translator, I thought of using something like this:

```
import React from "react";

export class Translator extends React.Component {
  originalContent = this.props.children

  arrayToTranslate = originalContent.getElementsByClassName('translate')

  // Here would be all the translating stuff and return arrayToTranslate with translated 
  text inside
  
  for(let i = 0; i < originalContent.getElementsByClassName('translate').length; i++) {
     originalContent.getElementsByClassName('translate')[i] = arrayToTranslate[i]
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {originalContent}
    );
  }
}
```

I know getElementsByClassName only exists for the 'document' DOM element, it's just to give you an idea of how I want to do it.
Unfortunately I couldn't find any way to make it work.

Last little note: the idea is to call my Translator component on as many potential Content components we need to translate, so that the translation is kind of "modular".

Sorry if I have not made this clear enough, or if it is a dumb question that has an obvious answer. I had to learn React from scratch in 3 days to start making this and I'm probably missing a lot of stuff that could be really useful.

Thanks in advance for your answers though! Let me know if some parts are unclear.

Comment: Remember, no question is dumb!
Anyway, I would do like this: setting empty div directly inside `<Translator>` and then inside Translator using React.Children's methods to iterate in them and check if they have any className that match with your's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try this way.

```
export default class Translator extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.translator()
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.translator()
  }
  translator() {
    const arr = document.getElementsByClassName('translate')
    // this is what you need
    console.log(arr)
  }
  render() {
    // children can be content or any React Component
    return this.props.children
  }
}
```

Comment: As I witnessed it in my multiple attempts, I don't think I can even use document.getElementsByClassName here because, as I understand it, it doesn't only refer to the child component, but to the whole rendered document.

Comment: so, get all "translate" DOM can not solve your problem?  You can call the Translator API in your top Component~ If you can not do it. You may need to use React.cloneElement to get the this.props.children DOM

Comment: I just realised I was focused on calling my API for each component eventhough doing it all at once with your method would just be more efficient. I'll try it, thanks!

Comment: If it is useful, Give me a like, thank you~ have a good day

Comment: I wanted to but I don't have enough reputation, sorry

Comment: No problem,I do not know "useful" button need reputation before.